# まえ sounds like まい?

Tags: pronunciation

I've found some audio files ([on Jisho for 前](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%89%8D-1), for example) that pronounce まえ just like I'd expect まい to be pronounced. I wasn't expecting that. Is there some rule about this?

Comment: Somewhat similar to "good day today" sounding like "good day to die"?

Comment: The audio is clearly different from まい so I recommend comparing with other words like 毎日（まいにち）and see if you can spot the difference. Being able to hear the difference between まえ and まい is important, and the audio you linked is not ambiguous.

Comment: If you are a speaker of English, it could be because you are expecting [ei] from え?

Comment: Well, /ae/ and /ai/ do have a sign of convergence on a lexical basis, but the audio clearly sounds まえ to me.

Comment: You're all correct. Now I can make myself hear either まえ or まい. I think @aguijonazo got it, and/or I was expecting a slightly longer え.